# Double sequences and iterated limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let a *double sequence* be defined as a function from $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, which we write as $(a_{m, n})$. We say that $(a_{m, n})$ *converges to $a$*, in symbols $(a_{m,n}) \to a$, if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there's $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for any $m, n > N$, $|a_{m, n} - a| < \varepsilon$. Suppose now that $(a_{m, n})$ converges to $a$ and suppose further that, for each $m$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_{m, n}) = b_m$. Its not very difficult to show that, under these conditions, $\lim_{m \to \infty}(\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_{m, n}))$ also exists and is in fact equal to $a$ (see [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20200331145646/http://www2.iugaza.edu.ps/ar/periodical/articles/volume%2014-%20Issue%201%20-studies%20-16.pdf) for a proof, and a rather detailed discussion of double sequences), by some explicit calculations. However, we also know that, if a double sequence $(a_{m, n})$ converges to some number $a$, every subsequence of $(a_{m, n})$ also converges to $a$ (see theorem 6.2 of the previous link).

> **Question:** Suppose then that $(a_{m, n})$ converges to $a$ and suppose further that, for each $m$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_{m, n}) = b_m$. Is it possible to prove that $\lim_{m \to \infty}(\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_{m, n})) = a$ using this result about subsequences?

I ask this because the proofs of the existence of the iterated limit that I've seen never appeal directly to this result, yet it seems to me to be a very natural way of proving it (in fact, when I attempted to prove it as an exercise from Abbott, that was my first thought). So am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean "under the above hypothesis? Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: @5xum - Sorry for the confusion. I wrote the question in more explicit terms now.

Comment: The point would be a proof by contradiction, i.e. trying to show that exist some subsequence that dont converges to $a$. Im reading the same book now, this is all that I can think about this question at this moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In effect you want to use Theorem $6.2$ to show that under the given hypotheses $\lim_{m\to\infty}b_m=a$. This is quite straightforward to do by contradiction. If not, there are an $\epsilon>0$ and a subsequence $\langle b_{m_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $|b_{m_k}-a|>\epsilon$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. Recursively choose $n_k$ for $k\in\Bbb N$ so that $n_{k+1}>n_k$ and $|a_{m_k,n_k}-b_{m_k}|<\frac{\epsilon}2$. Then on the one hand $|a_{m_k,n_k}-a|>\frac{\epsilon}2$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$, but on the other hand $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{m_k,n_k}=a$; this is clearly a contradiction.

Comment: Question: can't we say that, for each $m$, the sequence $(a_{m, n})$ (as $n$ varies) is a subsequence of the original one and then apply Theorem 6.2 directly?

Comment: @Nagase: No: you need to have both subscripts increasing without bound in order to ensure that the subsequence converges to $a$.

Comment: I see, thanks for this.

Comment: @Nagase: You’re welcome.