# Prove that if $\lim_{m,n\to\infty} a_{mn}$ exists and the iterated limits both exist, then all three limits must be equal. ("Understanding Analysis")

Tags: calculus, soft-question, double-sequence

I am reading "Understanding Analysis 2nd Edition" by Stephen Abbott.

> Define $\lim_{m,n\to\infty} a_{mn}=a$ to mean that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if both $m,n\geq N,$ then $|a_{mn}-a|<\epsilon.$

The iterated limits are $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{mn})$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{mn})$.

The following exercises are Exercise 2.3.13 (d) and (e) on p.56 in this book:

> (d) Assume $\lim_{m,n\to\infty}a_{mn}=a,$ and assume that for each fixed $m\in\mathbb{N},$ $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{mn}=b_m.$ Show $\lim_{m\to\infty} b_m=a.$
> (e) Prove that if $\lim_{m,n\to\infty} a_{mn}$ exists and the iterated limits both exist, then all three limits must be equal.

I wonder why the author didn't write as follows:

> (e)' Prove that if $\lim_{m,n\to\infty} a_{mn}$ exists and for each fixed $m\in\mathbb{N},$ $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{mn}$ exists and for each fixed $n\in\mathbb{N},$ $\lim_{m\to\infty} a_{mn}$ exists, then $\lim_{m\to\infty}(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{mn})$ and  $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{mn})$ exist and $\lim_{m,n\to\infty}a_{mn}$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{mn})$ and  $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{mn})$ must be equal.

I think (e)' is more natural than (e).

Why did the author write (e) instead of (e)'?

Comment: Maybe useful [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798647/double-sequences-and-iterated-limits)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much for your link.

Comment: Maybe the correct approach is to define what does it mean "iterated limit"... When in (d) the author writes "Assume that $\lim_{m,n \to \infty} \ldots$, have he previously defined what the symbol means?